# Xen Server Guest Network configuration?

Tags: virtualization, ubuntu, xen, xenserver

I am trying to install Ubuntu Server as a domU (Guest) on Citrix XenServer. Everything works fine but I am not able to access the internet from the guest. Is there any specific thing that I need to do to configure the network for the Guest. I have two NICs, 1 has an external IP and the other has an internal IP.

Comment: What does ifconfig show?

Comment: I am having a similar issue during install.

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed the XenServer guest tools?